# How can I bold an appended text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working on a project in which I'm wanting to make the appended text appear bold. Based on my research  it should be .bold() but that's not making my appended text bold, and is instead showing my text surrounded by "< b >< /b >". What am I doing incorrectly? Here is my code:

```
var breweryname=response.results[i].name;
    var breweryName = $("<p class='title'>").text(response.results[i].name.bold());
    breweryDiv.append(breweryName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.text()`, use `.html()` (ensure that you trust the response - you dont want any injection!) You could also make your CSS class `title` with `font-weight: bold` if you'd like to separate behavior and presentation.

Comment: That worked, thank you! I'll accept your answer shortly.

Comment: It's not even just about trusting the data... it's about ensuring it's properly escaped for the context.  All it takes is a poorly placed ampersand, and now the element is messed up.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **not** using `.html()` as it could have injections (Which you should avoid). `.name` is just a text `name` which you want it `bold` then keep using `.text`.

To apply css *(bold fonts)* to your dynamically added elements *(response.results[i].name)*.

You can simply use jQuery [.css](https://api.jquery.com/css/) function which will let you design your element as exactly as normal css is a much better approach.

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
//Div to append to
var breweryDiv = $('#breweryDiv')

//Response
var breName = 'Random Name' //response.results[i].name;

//Text
var breweryName = $("<p class='title'>").text(breName);

//Apply Css
$(breweryName).css({
  'font-weight': 'bold'
})

//Append Results
breweryDiv.append(breweryName);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="breweryDiv">

</div>
```